# Regular Expression to find a word that starts with 'JD' fixed word length, in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am not expert in regex, need your help in the following problem.

I need to find a word from an string that contains a letter starting with **JD** the length of the word is known i.e **20**.
 For this case suppose String is `"Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex with pattern and matcher classes.

```
"\\bJD\\w{18}\\b"
```

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice-versa*)

**Example:**

```
String s =  "Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bJD\\w{18}\\b").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**OR**

```
String s =  "Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)JD[A-Za-z\\d]{18}(?!\\S)").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
JD014600001678885621
```

Comment: Accept an answer which you likes the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `\bJD[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}\b` regex.

```
 String rx = "\\bJD[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}\\b";
```

*Explanation:*

- `\b` - Boundary
- `JD` - The first condition - these letters must be matched
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}` - any Latin characters from a to z (case-insensitive) or digits from 0 to 9
- `\b` - Boundary

You need to use a word boundary to match only those portions of text that start with "JD".

In case you have several JD strings in one text, you can match them all like this (see [sample program here](http://goo.gl/yiEVI5)):

```
public static void main(String []args){

    String str = "Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID\nYour shipment 918947344 was delivered at ABC JD024900901978985929 Piece ID";
    String rx = "(?<=^|\\b)JD[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}";
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
    Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
 }
```

Comment: `\b` covers `^` as well.No need to specify it again :)

Comment: @vks: I prefer to play it safest :) But again you are right.

Comment: @TarunChaudhary: Glad to help. I have also added the regex explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*(JD\\d{18}).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
JD014600001678885621
```

Comment: Here what is meaning for  "$1" i.e the reason you used this.

Comment: @TarunChaudhary - It means first *selected group*. i.e, the value inside the first `()`

Answer (score 0):

use a `Matcher` object and use `Matcher.find()` to find matches within the input string:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bJD\\d{18}\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Your shipment 6016499344 was delivered at ABC JD014600001678885621 Piece ID");
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group());
```